# Cannot read property 'push' of undefined when when using nested functions

Tags: javascript, tree, inorder

Why does the following code work

```
const inorderTraversal = (root) => {
    let out = []

    const traverse = (node) => {
        console.log(node)
        if (!node) return
        traverse(node.left)
        out.push(node.val)
        traverse(node.right)
    }
    traverse(root)
    return out
};
```

but this one does not

```
const inorderTraversal = (root) => {
    let out = []

    const traverse = (node,arr) => {
        if (!node) return
        traverse(node.left)
        arr.push(node.val)
        traverse(node.right)
    }
    traverse(root,out)
    return out
};
```

I need to modify the algorithm for multiple binary trees but when sending the array as a parameter instead of a global variable I get an `Cannot read property 'push' of undefined` error.

Comment: `arr` is the second parameter of the `traverse` function. When you call `traverse(node.left)` or `traverse(node.right)`, you're only passing one single argument.

Comment: You do not pass `arr` as a second parameter in `traverse(node.left)` and `traverse(node.right)`, it should be `traverse(node.left, arr)` and `traverse(node.right, arr)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your second second script, you wrote `traverse(node.right)`, but, because your `traverse` function now has two parameters and you only pass in one, `arr` is undefined. Then, in the recursive function call, you get a warning on the statement `arr.push(node.val)` because you are trying to call the `push` method on `arr` even though the variable is undefined. To fix the error, add `arr` as the second parameter of the function call.